# put numbered balls in four similar boxes of a specific capacity

Tags: permutations, combinations

Six persons waiting for two taxis with four vacant seats each. Need to find number of ways they can be seated if internal arrangement also matters.
is it (may be) 6c4 x 4! x (2c2 x 4!/ 2!)?
My logic is like this: We choose 4 persons from 6 in 6c4 ways, among them internal arrangement also matters, so 6c4 x 4!. And, after allotting 4 persons, remaining 2 persons will be chosen in 2c2 ways, since we have 2 vacant space and 2 persons, so arrangement in 4! / 2! ways, diving by 2! as two vacant spaces are identical, now, all multiplied together.
is it right thought? Please suggest.

Comment: you should consider the possibility that 3 people are seated in each taxi

Comment: So, is it 6c4 x 4! x (2c2 x 4!/ 2!) + 6c3 x 4! x (3c3 x 4!) ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the taxis themselves are considered distinct as well, let us view the question in a different way:

$\overbrace{\underbrace{\underline{~}}_{\text{seat 1}}~\underbrace{\underline{~}}_{\text{seat 2}}~\underbrace{\underline{~}}_{\text{seat 3}}~\underbrace{\underline{~}}_{\text{seat 4}}}^{\text{taxi 1}}~\overbrace{\underbrace{\underline{~}}_{\text{seat 1}}~\underbrace{\underline{~}}_{\text{seat 2}}~\underbrace{\underline{~}}_{\text{seat 3}}~\underbrace{\underline{~}}_{\text{seat 4}}}^{\text{taxi 2}}$

Let us instead treat these as:

$\underbrace{\underline{~}}_{\text{seat 1}}~\underbrace{\underline{~}}_{\text{seat 2}}~\underbrace{\underline{~}}_{\text{seat 3}}~\underbrace{\underline{~}}_{\text{seat 4}}
~\underbrace{\underline{~}}_{\text{seat 5}}~\underbrace{\underline{~}}_{\text{seat 6}}~\underbrace{\underline{~}}_{\text{seat 7}}~\underbrace{\underline{~}}_{\text{seat 8}}$

Pick which six of the eight seats are occupied:

Pick the arrangement of the people within those seats.

For a total of:

> $\binom{8}{6}6!=8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3$ possible arrangements.

If the taxis are not considered distinct, then we double-counted each scenario, so dividing by two will account for the symmetry.

Comment: So, do you mean that if we had two taxis, one 5-seater and another 3-seater, (obviously distinct) then the answer would be same as we are not considering taxis at all, rather considering the seats only?

Comment: It so happens that yes, the number of arrangements of six people into two distinct four-seater taxis is the same as the number of arrangements of six people into a 5-seater taxi and a 3-seater taxi.  This can be seen quickly by the fact that there is a **bijection** between the two scenarios, and therefore the count must be the same as well.

Comment: One of the major tools we have in combinatorics is the ability to reword and redescribe the specific scenario we are given to count into a different scenario with which we are more familiar and can count more easily (for example counting the number of ways of distributing identical cookies among children can be somewhat difficult, but counting the number of binary sequences of stars and bars with a specific number of each is rather trivial).

Answer (score 0):

Just to go over @JMoravitz point:

Whether you choose to keep 4 in one and 2 in the other (or) to keep 3 in one and 3 in the other, or 5 in a 5 seater and 1 in a three seater everthing is the same.  To illustrate:

$${8\choose4}.4!\times {4\choose2}2!={8\choose3}3!\times {5\choose3}3!={8\choose5}.5!\times {3\choose1}.1!=20160$$

Answer (score 0):

Actually the simplest solution is just to go on putting people one by one into the taxis,

allowing them to choose seats in whichever any way, hence $8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3 = 20160$,

and if you want to condense the expression, just $_8P_6 = 20160$